# Counter Strike freeze problem

Tags: 14.04, wine

Whenever I start to play counter strike on my Ubuntu 14.04 it freezes after 15 seconds. Is there any solution to it? Do note that I installed it using wine.

Comment: Wine still has many issues, so expect that

Comment: If you run wine from the command line, are the any error messages?